# Vertical space after scrollbar in Internet Explorer with iframe, how to remove it?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, iframe, scroll

I am trying to embed a URL in my webpage using iframe. The page is working properly on FireFox and Chrome, but on IE a vertical space is left after the scroll bar, how do I remove it ?

Here is the code along with CSS,

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding 0;
}
iframe {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
h1 {
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<iframe src="http://abc.org" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" ></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Regards,
Timothy

Comment: Which version of IE? In IE9 it looks the same as in Chrome.

Comment: On IE 9. Here is a screenshot of how it is with the iframe and without it http://i47.tinypic.com/294gaxc.png

Comment: Is this using the exact code that you included in your question?  I don't get double scrollbars in IE in I put this into a jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/H3YwZ/2/.

Comment: Yes I am using the exact code as in the question.

Comment: I think the reason I can't reproduce it is because you haven't used a proper doctype and IE is in quirks mode.  Replace <html> with <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: With DOCTYPE only a single scroll bar is shown but only a portion of the page is displayed and I need to scroll down to see the entire page.

Comment: You should never rely on quirks mode to get an effect that you want. Add height: 100% to your body, html css.

Comment: Adding height: 100% to body, html css gives double scroll bars on FireFox, Chrome and IE.

Comment: I tried searching on google about this and there was a similar question where someone suggested to use overflow-y: hidden; in html styling withing css. I did so and it worked. Is it the right way ?

Answer (score 0):

**This is you're complete solution :**

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
html {height:100%}
body {
margin:0;
height:100%;
overflow:hidden
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<iframe allowtransparency=true frameborder=0 id=rf sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-forms allow-scripts" scrolling=auto src="http://www.abc.org" style="width:100%;height:100%"></iframe>
</body>
```

Comment: The page I want to iframe is quite long and hence I need the scroll to work. If I set Scrolling="no", I won't be able to view the entire page.

Comment: I did try, but height attribute needs to be changed for every src attribute right ?

Comment: Yes I did and it worked. But in my page I need to add many iframes, and hence it wouldn't be ideal to change the height attribute everytime.

Comment: @TimothyBlack I have made the solution for you, try the new code. 
If it worked for you please vote the post :)